# How to update and delete entries from Chronicle Queue?

Tags: java, chronicle

I looked through the [Chronicle Java](http://openhft.github.io/Chronicle-Queue/apidocs/) doc and didn't see any methods to update and delete existing entries from the Chronicle queue. Does the Chronicle queue only support for WRITE/APPEND and READ operations only?

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Delete existing entries from the Chronicle-Queue is not supported however you can mark it as processed.

This may help: https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue#reading-the-chronicle-after-a-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar use case, with one server running continuously and answering requests from clients that are created and die at any time.

I just made the server react on a special "reset command" keywords, so that when a client is done reading the answer, it sends this reset command to the server, and the server then calls the method:

```
chronicle.clear()
```